# What digital camera resolution do I need to make a "zoomed-in" image on a website?

Tags: resolution, web, megapixels

Sorry for my English...I don't have much experience with digital cameras.

Right now. I'm building a Website and I'm creating a zoomed-in image like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ichder/Lot9pk3q/15/), where mousing over a smaller image displays a larger version above in a bigger window. So, I'm working with two versions of each image: a small one and a big one.

The big image has a resolution of 1280 x 854 pixels.

My question: now I'm looking to buy a cheap digital camera (on e-bay, I found a Kodak EasyShare V1233 (12,0 MP)), what is the minimum resolution I need for the big image?

Comment: I have to admit, I cannot figure out what the actual question is here - but it appears to be about web-coding, not photography.

Comment: Sorry for my English...my question is, when I to want to take an image and I'll later it to display as https://jsfiddle.net/ichder/Lot9pk3q/15/ , can do with a cheap digital camera ?

Comment: This appears to be a product photography question. It sounds like OP is asking what the minimum zoom amount is on an inexpensive digital camera to get a (probably decent resolution) to display images like these cars: [1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image1.jpg), [2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image2.jpg), [3](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/master/images/large/image3.jpg)

Comment: The first two images look like drawings (computer renderings) not photos.  I think taking car photos is something the OP needs to look up online for detailed advice, as just having a camera won't get you good photos of cars, particularly moving cars.

Comment: @scottbb, yes that is my question...

Comment: @shivam:  you don't need to fill the frame, as inksta says. That is a better answer than the one you accepted.  The image you are talking about is tiny in terms of pixels.  Getting everything stationary and properly lighted is your challenge.  Post processing can help a lot, but getting it right at the start is important, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use any digital camera with good amount of pixels (12 should suffice). You also need to make sure that the object is fairly lit in case its steady, or well lit in case its moving.

Also, I don't think you need to take two different photos if you want to make use of the interactive zoom feature on the website. You just need to capture one image and use the compressed image for normal zoom & the high res image for the zoomed version.
Hope that helps!

Comment: very Thanks for your anwer!, that was my question! I wish you a nice Day!

Comment: One more thing, try to fill your frame with the subject keeping less empty space. This will be helpful in the zoomed in version as the image will still remain fairly sharp even after zooming.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation!, can you to tell me how does it?

Answer (score 3):

Since your large image has a resolution of 1280 x 854, then all you need is a camera that can do 1280x854 => 1,093,120 pixels, or 1 megapixel (MP) or higher.  You could probably even use a frame capture from 1080 HD video (1920x1080 pixels) or a smartphone camera.

In other words, any digital camera with a resolution of more than 1 megapixel is likely to be fine for the web delivery size you want, and a 12MP camera is more than capable of giving you what you need here, in terms of pixels.

However. Product photography and car photography are specific disciplines that may require more expertise and additional gear than a simple low-cost digital camera, particularly when it comes to lighting. So if you wanted images that looked exactly like the ones you're using to test the web code, the EasyShare may not be quite capable of producing them, since it lacks a flash hotshoe, which makes lighting more difficult, and M exposure mode, which makes controlling exposure settings more difficult.

Comment: Sorry for my later answer...I to buy a Samsung ES25 Digital Camera second hand on eBay, in setting I'll give 1920X1080 because the smaller which it to have is 1024X768.. Many thanks for your recommendations!